# iphone App Deployment Question

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i have an app developed and ready for deployment. The client is expecting to use this app on around 100 - 150 devices.he would be adding and removing devices all the time. Does he have to buy the enterprise program or how does it go about installing the build file on all devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to install the app just on specific devices, say, within your organisation, you have to buy the Enterprise license. The other license is for App Store distribution only.

Comment: ok Lets assume he has bought the enterprise program license, does he still have to add the devices he needs to run the app on to the ios provisoing portal. my client is non-technical guy. he just wants the app and let it run on all devices he has.

Comment: No, he doesn't have to add the devices. He can post the app to a secure internal server where the users can visit and install from there. Or, he can do it via iTunes. Read this article on Enterprise Distribution to know the whole process. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979

Comment: so you are saying , if the user has enterprise account-all he has to do is build the code with the valid enterpise proviosing profile without having to add all the device ids to the portal whatsoever.he just can post the .app file to a secure webserver and everyone who has access to the .app file on the server can download it and install it on their ipad. Question 1) how does apple authenticate while installing the app to check if its being installed on the devices own by the company or enterprise.Qestion 2)is there a limit apple imposes on how many devices the app can be installed on.

Comment: Essentially, yes, that is what I am saying. In answer to your questions - I'm not sure there is any authentication - that's why it has to be posted to a secure webserver - only people who can log in get access ot it. 2. There doesn't see to be a limit - it makes no sense to add a limit - 100 users is a very small amount if you think in Corporate terms. Please, check out the documentation I linked above - it clearly explains the full process.

Answer (score 1):

You can add maximum 100 device using developer account. 
Othrewise you need to upload application to apple store.

Regards,
MAc

Comment: The 100 device limit is only for Ad Hoc distribution with individual developr account. In house distribution for Enterprise accounts have no such limit.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to submit it to appstore, that way the client can install it on all the devices he want.

Comment: But also so can anybody else! Which i think probalby isn't a good idea for a corporate.

Comment: he does not want the app to be on the appstore, he just wants it to run his business.

Answer (score 0):

Using AdHoc distribution, he can add upto 100 devices.But he cant go about deleting and adding.Each added device will permanently decrease the count.Else you will have to go through the appstore process

Comment: Sorry i missed to mentioned that.Yup its yearly.But i think for the purpose mentioned in the question, it would a barrier.

Comment: In House distribution is different from Ad Hoc distribution. It doesn't have the same limits, as far as I am aware. Also, you don't need to register the devices like you do with Ad Hoc distribution.